# Ajax submit without :remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

I have a form in my application which I need to submit via Ajax (JQuery), however It needs to get submitted remotely from my JavaScript (i.e. I can not user **:remote => true**).

I can locate my form in my JavaScript no problems:

```
my_form = $("#the_id_of_the_form");
```

Then I create my Ajax request:

```
$.post('hardcoded path?', function(data) {
  // how would I serialize my parameters?
});
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

**Example:** send form data using ajax requests

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

In your situation it can be something like that.

```
$('#your_form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not hardcode the url, instead use the url as stored in the form.

You can do this as follows:

```
$("#the_id_of_the_form").submit(function() {
    $.post({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize()
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery(<FORM_ID>).ajaxSubmit`

Your form should be something like following

```
<%= form_for @user,:url=>{:controller=>:logins, :action => 'sign_up'}, :html=>{ :onSubmit => "return checkSignupValidation()",:id=>"signup_form"}  do |f|%>

<% end %>
```

And your js

```
    function checkSignupValidation()
    {
      jQuery('#signup_form').ajaxSubmit({
        url:"/logins/sign_up",
        iframe: true,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data)
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use $.post or $.get, it is not agile and cause troubles in debug and refactoring/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'only_hardcore_path/' + my_form.serialize(),
  type: 'POST'  
});
```

or may be:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'only_hardcore_path/',
  type: 'POST',
  data: my_form.serialize()
});
```